# HTTPS with self-signed certificate produces handshake error

Tags: android, ssl, https, certificate

I'm trying to connect to a HTTPS web server via Android's `HttpClient` with a self-signed client and server certificates. Both certs and private key are stored in PKCS#12 keystore.

I'm using [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947162/https-and-self-signed-certificate-issue/5961919#5961919) with the difference in loading the keystore:

```
KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
trustStore.load(new FileInputStream(keystoreFile), "mypass".toCharArray());
```

The keystore loads properly as I'm able to list all certs in it.

But, when executing the GET request I get:

```
09-07 22:01:05.197: ERROR/TTT(3716): IOException: java.io.IOException: 
SSL handshake failure: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure 
(external/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1127 0x2e3b40:0x00000003)
```

I'm testing this on Nexus S with OS 2.3.4 and HTC Desire with OS 2.2 and also emulator with OS 2.1. They all produce the same error. I looked at [s3_pkt.c:1053](http://www.google.com/codesearch#XrPblB9f5NU/ssl/s3_pkt.c&q=s3_pkt.c&type=cs&l=1053) but couldn't understand what the problem could be.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
trustStore.load(new FileInputStream(keystoreFile), "mypass".toCharArray());
```

You seem to have your keystore and your truststore confused. The keystore contains your private key and certificate. The truststore contains other people's certificates.

Comment: I'm not an expert in this but it seems that a java.security.Keystore can contain all certs and private keys: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html

Comment: My keystore loaded from PKCS#12 file (.p12) sure does. I listed all entries and there they are: private key, CA cert and user cert. The "truststore" is just a name of variable from original example.

Comment: +1 You were right: I need to set the keystore and separately the truststore. They are the same file, but nevertheless you have to set it twice.

Comment: @Peter Knego Technically they are the same kind of file but from the security point of view they should be two separate files. That's why it's all specified that way. The keystore contains your private key and should be subject to very high security, as it is your identity. The truststore just contains other people's public certificates and there is nothing secure about them whatsoever. In a large organization the people entitled to modify the keystore would be different from the people entitled to modify the truststore.