# Trust all certificates? X509Certificate

Tags: android, https, x509certificate

I have following code which connects through HTTPS but i am getting following error during connection attempt.

> WARN/System.err(9456): javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
>   org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertPathValidatorException: Could not validate certificate signature.

How do i get this solved?
Trust all certificates? how do i do that?
It would be no issue as i only connect to the same server.
FY i already implemented EasyX509TrustManager as a class in my app.

Thank you in advance.

```
 try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            // Setting up parameters 
            SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry(); 
            // http scheme 
            schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80)); 
            // https scheme 
            schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", new EasySSLSocketFactory(), 443)); 

            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams(); 
            params.setParameter(ConnManagerPNames.MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS, 30); 
            params.setParameter(ConnManagerPNames.MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_ROUTE, new ConnPerRouteBean(30)); 
            params.setParameter(HttpProtocolParams.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false); 
            HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1); 

            ClientConnectionManager cm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, schemeRegistry); 

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(cm, client.getParams()); 


            // Example send HttpsPost request 
            final String url = "https://www.xxxx.com/web/restricted/form/formelement"; 

            // Do the HTTPS Post
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url); 

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters; 
            postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2); 
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("usr_name", username)); 
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("usr_password", password));

            System.out.println(postParameters); 

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            Log.w("Response ","Status line : "+ response.toString());
```

---

Hi Peter,

Thx for your answer, i followed your advise and the could not validate message is gone. However now i am getting the following message:

09-26 23:47:20.381: WARN/ResponseProcessCookies(10704): Cookie rejected: "BasicClientCookie[version=0,name=ObFormLoginCookie,domain=www.kpn.com,path=/web/restricted/form?formelement=512663,expiry=null]". Illegal path attribute "/web/restricted/form?formelement=512663". Path of origin: "/web/restricted/form/formelement=512663"
09-26 23:47:20.461: WARN/Response(10704): Status line : org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@407afb98

So something seems to be wrong in the headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't trust all certificates, that is a very, very bad idea. Create a keystore with your server's certificate, put in the app's raw assets, and load it into HttpClient's [SSLSocketFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html). Then register this factory for https in the `SchemeRegistry`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide your own `TrustManager` which trusts all certificates.

See this answer: [HTTPS and self-signed certificate issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947162/https-and-self-signed-certificate-issue/5961919#5961919)

Comment: Hi Peter,please see my edited message above..
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The cookie being sent is does not match path defined in the cookie. Thre is a "?" instead of "/"