# Executing a POST-request in Android

Tags: android, http

I'm basically trying to get my app to do the following command

curl -i -X POST -d "user=*USER*&pass=*PASS*" https://websitehere.com

But I don't understand the solutions I've found so far. If I use a HttpPost to post nameValuePairs what should these be?

I also get an IOException with the information ssl-certificate-not-trusted-error when the httpclient.execute(httppost); command is done.

```
public void postData(String userString, String passString) {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://websitegoeshere.com");
        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", userString));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", passString));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));


            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);



        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {               
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your certificate isnt valid. Test it out here: https://www.digicert.com/help/index.htm

Comment: The site you linked said it was valid.

Comment: Some certificates not are liked by android because although valid, are missing some intermediate certs, talk to you cert provider.

Comment: Can anyone comment on the structure of the nameValuePairs, should it be like that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore the SSL cert error, because you do trust the site, you need to provide your own `TrustManager` which trusts all certificates.

Refer to: [HTTPS and self-signed certificate issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947162/https-and-self-signed-certificate-issue/5961919#5961919)

Comment: Thanks for responding. The owner of the site are claiming to have a valid and working, could I be doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try this means to authenticate:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://websitegoeshere.com");
try {
    UsernamePasswordCredentials creds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password);
    post.addHeader(new BasicScheme().authenticate(creds, post));
} catch (AuthenticationException e) {
    // Handle Exception
}
```