# How to check Fingerprint of self-signed SSL Certificate on Android?

Tags: android, ssl, self-signed

I have a self-signed SSL Certificate and an Android App that should only trust this one specific Certificate. I use the solution from [HTTPS and self-signed certificate issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947162/https-and-self-signed-certificate-issue) to accept all Certificates, how do I check the Certificate Fingerprint and reject all other?

Comment: http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-custom-certificate-trust-store-on.html